# Using FirstOrDefault() in query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Is there a way to use `FirstOrDefault()` inside a complex query but not throw an exception if it returns null value?

#### My query:

```
contex.Table1.Where(t => t.Property == "Value").FirstOrDefault()
             .Object.Table2.Where(t => t.Property2 == "Value2").FirstOrDefault();
```

If the query on the first table (Table1) doesn't return an object the code throws an exception. Is there a way to make it return just null?

Comment: i don't know if C# / .NET has a Null-Object, which could be returned as default, but you should checkout the null object pattern

Comment: Why not use 2 query instead of 1?

Comment: I need to do it in the same query about perfomarce issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a `SelectMany` on `Table2`, without the intermediate `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
context.Table1.Where(t1 => t1.Property1 == "Value1")
              .SelectMany(t1 => t1.Table2.Where(t2 => t2.Property2 == "Value2"))
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, you might want to use SQL Profiler to check the SQL that is being sent by EF.  I believe the query as constructed in your question will result in two queries being sent to the database; one for each `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could build your own helper function, that takes IEnumerable

```
public static TSource CustomFirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault() ?? new List<TSource>();
}
```

This would effectively return an empty list, which, when called upon, providing your code in your Object property can handle nulls, won't bomb out, cause you'll just be returning a 0 item collection, instead of a null.

Comment: This won't work as you're attempting to return a single TSource OR a List<TSource> depending on the result of FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 1):

Only the first query with `Where` is a database query. As soon as you apply a "greedy" operator like `FirstOrDefault` the query gets executed. The second query is performed in memory. If `Object.Table2` is a collection (which it apparently is) and you don't have lazy loading enabled your code will crash because the collection is `null`. If you have lazy loading enabled a second query is silently executed to load the collection - the *complete* collection and the filter is executed in memory.

You query should instead look like @adrift's code which would really be only one database query.